# Can't set neovim colors to follow terminal colors in st terminal

Tags: neovim, colorscheme, st

I can't set neovim colors to follow terminal colors in `st` terminal.
Here is a screenshot from the terminal:
[image]

I have tried different configurations of `set t_Co=256` and `set termguicolors` but all of them give different color schemes such as:
[image]
[image]

What is interesting is the fact that colors from terminal theme work by default in vim but do not work in neovim.

Answer (score 2):

**SOLVED!**

The problem was the background variable, which was set to dark.

```
set background=light
```

solves the issue.